# use 'mutableState' value in init of viewmodel

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

i defined a
`var showAllEvent = mutableStateOf(false)` in my viewmodel
and want to use it in
`init {}` of my viewmodel,
but when use, give me this error:
`IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied`
how can i use my value in `init` of my viewmodel` in jetpack compose

```
@HiltViewModel
class EventPageVM @Inject constructor(
private val repository: EventRepository,
private val noteRepository: NoteRepository
) : ViewModel() {

private val _eventsList = MutableStateFlow<List<Event>>(emptyList())
val eventsList = _eventsList.asStateFlow()
///
var showAllEvent = mutableStateOf(false)
var showPastEvent = mutableStateOf(true)


init {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val fromTo = Extra.getFromToNextMonth(CivilDate())
        val start= if (showPastEvent.value)null else fromTo[0]
        val end=if (showAllEvent.value)null else fromTo[1]
        repository.getEvents(start, end).distinctUntilChanged().collect { result ->
            _eventsList.value = result
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you have the `mutableStateOf` in the viewModel what's the advantage? Can you use a `MutableStateFlow`

Comment: If you use compose apis in the viewmodel you are making it cumbersome the testing with that decision. Use flows instead and collect them on the compose side.

Comment: This is what you need to know: https://jetc.dev/slack/2022-05-16-mutating-state-viewmodel-constructor.html

Comment: You're just not supposed to use `mutableStateOf` in the ViewModel. It should be `savedStateHandle.getStateFlow()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess states created using `mutableStateOf` should be written/read from the UI thread. Currently you use `Dispatchers.IO` which means that the state is read in the background thread. Try to use `Dispatchers.Main` context in code where you work with the state:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val fromTo = Extra.getFromToNextMonth(CivilDate())
        val start = if (showPastEvent.value) null else fromTo[0]
        val end = if (showAllEvent.value) null else fromTo[1]
        repository.getEvents(start, end).distinctUntilChanged().collect { result ->
            _eventsList.value = result
        }
    }
}
```

`viewModelScope.launch` by default uses `Dispatchers.Main` context.

Another approach is to use `Flow`s in the `ViewModel` and [collect](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) them in the Compose functions.

Comment: connect to repository can not run in Main thread

Comment: why? doesn't it return a `Flow`? Do you have errors or ui freezes? You can also provide the code of the repository to have a whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue and opted to move initialization to a `LaunchedEffect` in a Jetpack Compose project. Though the approach of initializing state in the init block seemed useful at first it became a pain when attempting to run instrumented tests.

Here's a lengthy write up on the subject: https://jetc.dev/slack/2022-05-16-mutating-state-viewmodel-constructor.html